# Get the max number of grandchildren per child object

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

My setup consists of a League model, which can have many Game models tied to it, and each Game can have 2 or more Team models tied to the *game*.  For a particular League, I'd like to display a table of games and their teams in a table like:

```
Game | Team | Team | Team | Team
1    | 1    | 2    | 3    | 5
2    | 2    | 7    | 9    |
3    | 4    | 1    | 2    |
```

In order for me to do this, I I need to know how many columns to make ahead of time which means I need to know, for a particular league, the max number of teams tied to any of the games in the league.  I can think of two ways to do this:

1. In my view, do some type of query to get the answer and feed it to the context data
2. In my template, determine the max by a series of loops

I like #2 because I feel like #1 is using View logic to do presentation work which is bad, but #1 seems like it'd be quicker.  Is there another way and/or can someone give me advice on the actual implementation?

Comment: What do you mean by "a League model can have many Game models tied to it"? Be more explicit. Maybe you meant "many object instances" instead of models. And what does tied mean for you? Foreign Key? And does your view serve a particular League? like ``/league/id``?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but I have a feeling you are over complicating it i.e. making this a ``traversal tree`` model. From what I can tell this is a simple one-to-many relationship you have. One Game has many Teams. So all you would do is get the total ``Team.objects.filter(game=x).count()``

Comment: you want to say "game instances" instead of game models, they are individual objects made from the game model.

Comment: Example: League = {Bowling League}.  League.Teams = {Ducks, Bears, Sharks, Lizards}.  League.Games = {Game1, Game2}.  Game1.Teams = {Ducks, Bears Sharks}.  Game2.Teams = {Lizards, Bears}.  So, on the Bowling League page, I want to display a table with two rows for the games and three columns for the teams per game.

Comment: @BenGorman Thanks, that helps. You should use a model method to get the game.team_count() and then in the template you'll do a for loop in the template for game.team_count() iterations for the columns. IF you decide to do something in the view and pass via context, put the code to get the teamcount in a shared module, not in the view directly (so it is reusable)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your actual code I'm just guessing. If you want the count in your request for each Team in a Game you can easily append this to the context. For example, using a Class Based View you can overwrite `get_context_data()`

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super(YOURGAMEVIEWCLASS, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
    context['team_count'] = Team.objects.filter(game=x).count()
    return context
```

Note: Django's generic class based views now automatically include a view variable in the context so there are better ways: http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2014/05/19/context.html

....But if all you want to do is get the count of an object you already have then I see no reason why you cannot do this in the template i.e. `{{ teams.count }}`. After all, you are only using it for persentation I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand, but let me give my suggestion on how I perceive the question.

It's best to put the logic on the model if possible, almost always. Is there a way you can put a max_team_count model method on the Game model to get your solution?

That way in the template or the view you can call the game.max_team_count() method and have it available everywhere from the model method instead of repeating the logic in views or templates.

Comment: I have to disagree with you...I think that the MVC/MVT architecture should be respected. I would only put in models fields and, eventually, properties. Less code isn't always the best solution. Moreover, you don't have to repeat yourself in the view. You can make reusable stuff and use the view for the purposes it is created: to calculate and to do logic inside. So not in the template, not in the model, but in the view

Comment: with MVC it's best to put it on the model. It's not more code, it's just putting the logic in the model rather than the view/template which makes the logic more portable. If you put it in the view layer, it should go in a utils.py, but that still requires it be imported from the utils.py file rather than being attached to the model, everywhere, always.

Comment: Exactly, ``everywhere and always`` are obtained by making it on the model. And we don't want this. Most probably he only needs this query for that view. This method will never be used anymore in other places. What are you saying is equivalent to making methods on a model for any query that is used in any view, which is totally absurd

Comment: the function is not called on every query. It's not called on anything dealing with Query nor QuerySet. It's only called when you invoke the function. It is loaded on the import, but that's very minimal.

Comment: Of course. What I meant earlier, you probably misunderstood me, is that you won't make a method on a model every time you need to query that model. You will make the query in the view instead of implementing methods containing queries in the model. This is a generalization